# VSE: zooming into preview area

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, shortcut

Any way to zoom into my preview range "10900 - 11450" using shortcuts or functions?

[image: 1]

Actually I can zoom into this area on the timeline using the <kbd>home</kbd> button but on the sequencer it will only zoom out to the whole work area...

[image: 2]

Here you can see how the same button <kbd>home</kbd> zooms out on a different way..

---

What I'm searching for is something like the <kbd>P</kbd> button that sets the preview area and then something like an <kbd>AltGr + p</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + p</kbd> to zoom into the area in order to reach a status like this:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to zoom in the *Timeline* by drawing a rectangle while holding down <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Doing this you will zoom in to the rectangle you draw.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. He asked about how to zoom this very area in the VSE, not in the timeline!?

Comment: Shift+b also works in the VSE

Comment: Oh - it's working somehow for me now... it's just zooming in vertically as well.

Comment: How to zoom back out (without mmb)?  The scroll bar can be dragged to rescale horizontally without changing the vertical zoom - but then now I want to reset the vertical zoom.

Comment: I see there is a vertical scroll bar also that can be stretched.